# in Django basehttp.py getting ImproperlyConfigured on app_path = apollo.wsgi.application

Tags: python, django, wsgi

When I run **python manage.py check** I get no errors.  However when I try to **runserver** I get...

```
File "C:\Users\oliver\apollodev\django-apollo-forms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 50, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'apollo.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

The offending code block is...

```
   try:
        print("/////////////////////////basehttp.py app_path = ", app_path )
        return import_string(app_path)
    except ImportError as err:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "WSGI application '%s' could not be loaded; "
            "Error importing module." % app_path
        ) from err
```

I added the Print() to see what is going on and get...

```
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
/////////////////////////basehttp.py app_path =  apollo.wsgi.application
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oliver\apollodev\django-apollo-forms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 48, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    return import_string(app_path)
```

settings.py has WSGI_APPLICATION = 'apollo.wsgi.application'set.

I tried adding **apollo.wsgi.application** to INSTALLED_APPS but got a new error...

```
File "C:\Users\oliver\apollodev\django-apollo-forms\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 83, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
```

At a loss on what to try next.

Comment: It might happen because of not having all dependencies. have you tried running ' pipenv install ' ?

Comment: I was using venv and did all my installs with pip install inside the venv activated shell.  Should I give up on venv and go to pipenv instead?

Comment: I use pipenv. Switching is up to you

Answer (score 0):

I found that when I moved the project with the embedded venv to a new folder, it stopped working properly.  I suppose the best thing is to create the venv outside the project with a project unique name.  That worked for me when I recreated the venv.  I must have discipline to update requirements.txt when I add a new module so it will be eaiser to rebuild the venv if it becomes corrupt again.

Hope this helps others.